# Change h.264 quality when using SinkWriter to encode video

Tags: windows-7, encoding, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I am using Microsoft Media Foundation to encode a H.264 video file.

I am using the SinkWriter to create the video file. The input is a buffer (`MFVideoFormat_RGB32`) where I draw the frames and the output is a `MFVideoFormat_H264`.

The encoding works and it creates a video file with my frames in it. But I want to set the quality for that video file. More specifically, I want to set the [`CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property on the H.264 encoder.

In order to get a handle to the H.264 encoder, I call [GetServiceForStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the SinkWriter. Then I set the `CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality` property.

The problem is that my property change is ignored. As stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#codec_properties):

> To set this parameter in Windows 7, set the property before calling IMFTransform::SetOutputType. The encoder ignores changes after the output type is set.

The problem is that I don't create the H.264 encoder manually. I set the input and the output type on the SinkWriter, and the SinkWriter creates the H.264 encoder automatically. As soon as it creates the encoder, it calls the `IMFTransform::SetOutputType` method, and I can't change the `CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality` property anymore. The documentation also says that the property change isn't ignored in Windows 8, but I need this to run on Windows 7.

Do you know how I can change the quality for the encoded file while using SinkWriter on Windows 7?

PS: [Someone asked the same question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mediafoundationdevelopment/thread/6da521e9-7bb3-4b79-a2b6-b31509224638) on the msdn forums, and he didn't seem to get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation says, you just can't change the `CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality` property after the output type is set, and the SinkWriter sets the output type before you can get a hand on the encoder.

In order to bypass this problem I managed to create a class factory and register it in Media Foundation, so that the SinkWriter uses it to create a new encoder. In my class factory, I create a new H264 encoder and set whatever properties I want before passing it on to the SinkWriter.

I have written in more detail the steps I took to create this class factory on the MSDN forums, here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/mediafoundationdevelopment/thread/6da521e9-7bb3-4b79-a2b6-b31509224638

That was the only way I could get around my problem on Windows 7.

Comment: I understand it's been so long since you have worked on this, I followed your code but I'm not getting CreateInstance called, but only getting QueryInterface called for interfaces IID_IMFAttributes and IID_IClassFactory instead. I returned the instance of my class factory for IID_IClassFactory, and queried IMFTransform for IID_IMFAttributes, but nothing worked as expected after that point. SinkWriter seems to be enumerating MFT on its own. Could you please tell me what should I do in the QueryInterface?

Comment: @Ram I have updated the MSDN thread with my old implementation of QueryInterface. You can check that out and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

`CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode` and `CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality` can be passed to the h.264 encoder using `IMFSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(/* ... */,, IMFAttributes pEncodingParameters)`.  I suspect other `CODECAPI_` values would work as well.

```cpp
CComPtr<IMFAttributes> pEncAttrs;
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(MFCreateAttributes(&pEncAttrs, 1));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pEncAttrs->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, eAVEncCommonRateControlMode_Quality));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pEncAttrs->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, 40));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(writer->SetInputMediaType(sink_stream, mtSource, pEncAttrs));
//                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```