# Set attributes via ICodecAPI for a H.264 IMFSinkWriter Encoder

Tags: h.264, video-encoding, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to tweak the attributes of the H.264 encoder created via ActivateObject() by retrieving the ICodecAPI interface to it.
Although I do not get errors, my settings are not taken into account.

Code runs under Windows 10.

I copy the code I use to create the IMFSinkWriter and retrieve the ICodecAPI below. Error handling not shown, but no error are produced.

I have read this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed3b6597-2566-43e8-b7c5-4472c0425245/imfsinkwriter-set-icodecapi-parameters?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment) which implies that tweaking the encoder used by IMFSinkWriter may not be possible, but since there's no statement on the MSDN documentation I'd like to hear if anyone has managed to use the ICodecAPI with IMFSinkWritter.

If not possible, what would be the way to proceed? I need to encode in H.264 and stream to MP4. I want to change the GOP, Qp, CABAC, etc. which does not seem to be possible via the output media type.
I should be able to create the encoder separately and hook it to a MP4 file writer? Any pointers as to how to do this appreciated...

```cpp
hr = encoderToOpen.activate->ActivateObject(__uuidof(IMFTransform), (LPVOID *)&encoderTransform);
hr = encoderTransform->GetAttributes(&attributes);
hr = attributes->SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS, TRUE);
hr = MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(fileName, NULL, attributes, &encoder);

// Initialise outputMediaType (code not shown)

hr = encoder->AddStream(outputMediaType, &streamIndex);
hr = encoder->SetInputMediaType(streamIndex, sourceMediaType, NULL);

// Retrieve the ICodecAPI
ICodecAPI *codecApi;
streamIndex = 0;
hr = encoder->GetServiceForStream(streamIndex, GUID_NULL, __uuidof(ICodecAPI), (LPVOID*)&codecApi);

VARIANT v;
hr = codecApi->GetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, &v);
v.vt = VT_UI4;
v.ulVal = 8;
hr = codecApi->SetValue(&CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize, &v);

// Start encoding (code not shown)
```

Comment: C++ is apparently only minor related. That the code is written in c++ and not in c# or visual basic is just by chance I believe. You might consider to open your question for a broader audience by removing the c++ tag, and tell in the question that the actual code shown is written using c++.

Comment: Also you don't have a single error check in your code. You might want to test if your calls succeeded using the `hr` results.

Comment: Similar problem [Change h.264 quality when using SinkWriter to encode video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13287396/change-h-264-quality-when-using-sinkwriter-to-encode-video) ?

Comment: Re-C++ - ok, thanks. Error checking omitted for clarity, but no error generated in my app.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Were you able to solve this problem? If yes, could you please direct me to a sample or some documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Media Foundation's Sink Writer is a simplified API with a encoder configuration question slipped away. The fundamental problem here is that you don't own the encoder MFT and you are accessing it over the writer's head, then the behavior of encoders around changing settings after everything is set up depends on implementation, which is in encoder's case a vendor specific implementation and might vary across hardware.

Your more reliable option is to manage encoding MFT directly and supply Sink Writer with already encoded video.

Your potential trick to make things work with less of effort is to retrieve `IMFTransform` of the encoder as well and clear and then set back the input/output media types after you finished with `ICodecAPI` update. Nudging the media types, you suggest that encoder re-configures the internals and it would do this already having your fine tunings. Note that this, generally speaking, might have side issues.

> The 'trick' seems to work for some of the ICodecAPI parameters (e.g. CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed) and only for Microsoft's h.264 encoder. No effect on CODECAPI_AVEncH264CABACEnable. The doc indeed seems to be specifically for Microsoft's encoder and not be a generic API. I'm using the QuickSync and NVidia codecs, do you know if those are configurable via the ICodecAPI assuming I create the MFT myself?

Vendor provided encoders fall under [Certified Hardware Encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/h-264-video-encoder#certified-hardware-encoder) requirements, so they must support `ICodecAPI` values mentioned in the MSDN article. Important is that it is not defined what the order of configuration calls is. If you are managing encoder yourself you would do `ICodecAPI` setup before setting up media types. In Sink Writer scenario it already configured the media types, then you jump in with your fine tuning. Hence, my trick suggestion includes the part of resetting existing media types. Because this trick is sensitive to implementation details I would suggest to get current media types, then clear them on the MFT, do `ICodecAPI` thing and get the types back. I assume that this should work in greater number of scenarios, not just MS encoder. Yet it still remains an unreliable hack.

IMO Nvidia's encoder implementation is terrible (worst across vendors), Intel's is better but it still has its own issues. Again IMO the MFTs are only provided to meet minimal certification requirements for hardware video encoding and for this reason their implementation is not well aligned. Various software packages prefer to implement video encoding via vendor SDKs rather than Media Foundation Transform interface. In one of the projects I used to also skip the idea of leveraging MFTs for encoding, and implemented my own MFTs on top of vendor SDKs.

> Would the class factory approach in this post work with the `IMFSinkWriter`?  This would avoid writing too much code...

I suppose that yes, this should work even though I feel that it's not a pleasant work to patch it that way. Also you might need to take into account support of HW encoders because Sink Writer also tends to use hardware assisted encoding in some cases, including scenario where it's given a DXGI device.

Another sort of a hack, which is similar but maybe a bit less intrusive (although in its implementation you would have to have a better understanding of internals) is to redefine vendor specific encoder CLSIDs within Sink Writer initialization scope. There are just three encoders (AMD, Intel, Nvidia; okay there is fourth from Shanghai Zhaoxin Semiconductor but it is not really popular) and their CLSIDs are known. If you `CoRegisterClassObject` in a smart way, you could hook MFT instantiation letting Media Foundation to decide which encoder to choose. It is just another idea though, so it might depend what is the best to do on other factors.

Comment: The 'trick' seems to work for _some_ of the ICodecAPI parameters (e.g. CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed) and only for Microsoft's h.264 encoder. No effect on CODECAPI_AVEncH264CABACEnable. [The doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/h-264-video-encoder) indeed seems to be specifically for Microsoft's encoder and not be a generic API. I'm using the QuickSync and NVidia codecs, do you know if those are configurable via the ICodecAPI assuming I create the MFT myself?

Comment: Would the class factory approach in this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6da521e9-7bb3-4b79-a2b6-b31509224638/win7-h264-encoder-imfsinkwriter-cant-use-quality-vbr-encoding?forum=mediafoundationdevelopment) work with the IMFSinkWritter? This would avoid writing too much code...

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly `ICodecAPI` from the client side, but `CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize` and `CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality` can be passed to the h.264 encoder using `IMFSinkWriter->SetInputMediaType(/* ... */,, IMFAttributes pEncodingParameters)`.  I suspect other `CODECAPI_` values would work as well.

```
CComPtr<IMFAttributes> pEncAttrs;
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(MFCreateAttributes(&pEncAttrs, 1));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pEncAttrs->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, eAVEncCommonRateControlMode_Quality));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pEncAttrs->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, 40));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(pEncAttrs->SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncMPVGOPSize, 4));
ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(writer->SetInputMediaType(sink_stream, mtSource, pEncAttrs));
//                                                                   ^^^^^^^^^
```

GOP setting can be verified to have taken effect as viewed on [MP4Box.js / ISOBMFF Box Structure Viewer](https://gpac.github.io/mp4box.js/test/filereader.html).  Quality can be observed to affect file size.